# Azure Key Vault portal not showing secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I'm having troubles understanding why my Azure Key Vault is not showing secrets (that were created automatically by importing certificates) in the portal.

[image: Azure Key Vault showing no secrets]

However, using the command line I can get them (redacted):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9>az keyvault secret list --vault-name <my vault>
[
  {
    "attributes": {
      "created": "2020-03-05T14:48:37+00:00",
      "enabled": true,
      "expires": "2021-01-28T19:23:00+00:00",
      "notBefore": "2018-01-29T19:23:00+00:00",
      "recoveryLevel": "CustomizedRecoverable+Purgeable",
      "updated": "2020-03-05T14:48:37+00:00"
    },
    "contentType": "application/x-pkcs12",
    "id": "https://<my vault>.vault.azure.net/secrets/SomeSecret",
    "managed": true,
    "tags": null
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "created": "2020-03-06T13:10:32+00:00",
      "enabled": true,
      "expires": "2021-01-28T19:23:00+00:00",
      "notBefore": "2018-01-29T19:23:00+00:00",
      "recoveryLevel": "CustomizedRecoverable+Purgeable",
      "updated": "2020-03-06T13:10:32+00:00"
    },
    "contentType": "application/x-pkcs12",
    "id": "https://<my vault>.vault.azure.net/secrets/SomeSecret2",
    "managed": true,
    "tags": null
  }
]
```

I've also authenticated my web application, and I'm able to get this secret and use it without problems from it (using [Azure Identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity), [Azure.KeyVault.Certificates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates) and [Azure.KeyVault.Secrets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets)).

**Why are my secrets not showing in the Azure Portal?** Is this because they were added automagically by importing a certificate? What happens if I delete a certificate?

Comment: is there any chance that secrets were created using a different credential and the one used in the portal has no list / get permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. If the secret was added automatically by importing a certificate, it will not appear in the `Secrets` in your keyvault in the azure portal.

Not only the SDK you mentioned, but also [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-3.5.0), [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-list), [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret/getsecret), they can all get the secret. You can also find the `Secret Identifier` in the `Certificates` -> your certificate, then use it directly in the REST API.

[image]

Comment: That's a really ugly (if not bad) design. The nuget package is consistent with this - when you get a certificate, you also get a full URI, which is useless (you need to split the URI to get the secret name so you can get the private key)