Adding Azure Key Vault Object by wizard on Visual Studio 2022 not visible on Azure Portal Key Vault
I'm adding dependencies for my ASP.NET MVC Project with

Azure Key Vault
Azure SQL Database

All dependencies are connected successfully. I've got my environment variable at Azure App Service / Settings / Environment Variables and connected to my Azure Key Vault URL. I wanted to add connection strings to azure key vault but somehow I don't see any object even keys or secret or certificate under my key vault Objects.

My question, where is my Connection Strings?
How to see it under the Azure Portal?
Also following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/azure-sql-database-add-connected-service?view=vs-2022#connect-to-azure-sql-database-using-connected-services I'm adding the SQL Database dependencies.
This one for the Key Vault https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service?view=vs-2022#add-key-vault-support-to-your-project
Referenced this question on S/O https://stackoverflow.com/a/60594690/1533670 that the object is not visible. Is it correct? By the way, I adding the Azure Key Vault and Azure SQL Database by Wizard under publish menu on the project.
Also, I have added Key Vault Administrator under Access Control Key Vault to my Account.


Hi, could you please go to the Secrets blade to see whether your keys are over there? By the way, in your application, you shall follow this document to get the configuration, and we don't require connection string of the Azure key vaults to connect to Azure key vaults

Connection strings are stored as secrets, not keys. Keys are asymmetric keys in Key Vault, and asymmetric or symmetric keys (AES) in Managed HSM. It's also worth noting that, depending on the app template you used, the app is authenticating as a different principal than you when you visit the portal. Different principals can also have different permissions. Check the "IAM" blade or, if using legacy access policies, the "Access policies" blade.

I am able to see the connection strings under the secrets section of the KeyVault.

Thanks @Tiny Wang and @Heath for the comments.
Yes, I am able to see the Connection String of SQL DB in the Secrets section of the Azure Key Vault.

For the SQL DB, while configuring locally you will get the below options.



Select the Save Connection string value as  Azure Keyvault. Now you can see the Connection String in Key Vault => Secrets.



I don't see any option for Key Vault to store the secrets in Azure KeyVault.

Configuring the Dependencies will allow you to connect with the specified instance (by installing the required packages) and may not create secrets (in case of Key Vault).



where is my Connection Strings? How to see it under the Azure Portal?


Initially when you configure the dependencies locally and deploy the app, by default they are visible under the Environment variable section of the Azure App Service (which you are able to see).



